# Dealing with same user multiple posts & not enough details

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

This question relates to a user that has opened a plethora of questions(7), in an attempt to get the same rough question answered.

The problem in my opinion is this user hasn't given enough details in any of them to receive an adequate answer. (The answers to the questions can only be generic). As far as I can see, this user does not respond to comments asking for clarification & additional details. Additionally, It seems this user in almost every question tries to change the scope of the question in the comments section to try and gather more information, instead of just forming one well researched question.

Normally I would vote to close as needing additional details. But wanted to make sure I was on the same page with the rest of the community with this. **Is this the proper response?**
I am certainly not trying to be a closure troll...

The mentioned users profile: https://superuser.com/users/1177888/threeemianichole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem in my opinion is this user hasn't given enough details in any of them to receive an adequate answer. (The answers to the questions can only be generic). As far as I can see, this user does not respond to comments asking for clarification & additional details.

If a question requires clarification, and the author of the question refuses to clarify the question, then the question should be closed.

> Additionally, It seems this user in almost every question tries to change the scope of the question in the comments section to try and gather more information, instead of just forming one well researched question.

Unnecessary commentary should be flagged as “no longer needed”, questions asked in the comment section of an answer, should be flagged for removal.  Specifically, if the scope of the questions within the commentary, drifts continuously without any sign of stopping.

> Normally I would vote to close as needing additional details. But wanted to make sure I was on the same page with the rest of the community with this. Is this the proper response? I am certainly not trying to be a closure troll.

Closing a bad question is encouraged, keeping bad quality questions, only does the community a disservice.

Comment: Well said, that pretty much clears it up for me. Thanks for taking the time to write this.

Comment: In the question I was dealing with, the question was quite clear (and lots of people have this question). The problem was the user kept changing the goal posts in the comments.

Comment: @John - By editing the question?  If the question was being modified several times, a moderator should be contacted, if these additional questions are just commentary just flag and ignore.  Ever expanding question doesn’t work.

Comment: @John - Sounds like unnecessary commentary to me